# Destroy shortest path in graph

Tags: graph-theory

Given graph G(V,E)and two vertices A and B, show how to eliminate the least number of edges so that length of shortest path between A and B become longer.(I need an algorithm)

Comment: Are all the edge lengths 1?

Comment: @PeterShor yes.

Comment: Please check [about] and [help/on-topic]. This question seems more suitable for [cs.se] which has a broader scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run BFS from $A$, and generate a graph $G'=(V,E')$ that consists only of the edges that are on some shortest path from $A$ to $B$ (i.e. $(x,y)\in E'$ iff $d(a,y)=d(a,x)+1$).

And your answer is the minimal $A-B$ cut in $G'$.

Comment: this algorithm eliminate all edges in shortest path but question want minimum number of edges that if removed the shortest path become longer.

Comment: @R B-do you mean that for removing all shortest path we must remove $i$th  edge of the path? is it the least number of such edges?

Comment: @amineh - see my revised answer, the minimal cut is exactly what you're looking for, the proof is easy as well.